# jQuery Filter Variant 3: From DOM Element Array (Not Selector)

Tags: jquery

The jQuery `.filter()` documentation says that a 3rd way of using it is from `elements` which is not a Selector but DOM element(s) -- which I tested as an element array. But the following doesn't work. Can I filter from a custom Array of Elements?
http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```js
var subset = [];
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i, item) {
   subset.push($(this));
});

// Filter by Elements array
 $('input').filter(subset).each(function(i, item) {
    console.log('Filtered from array: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
 });
 console.log('end');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1"/><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea1"/><br/>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogroup"/>Radio1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogroup"/>Radio2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radiogroup"/>Radio3<br/>

<input type="text" id="text2"/><br/>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to filter from the array and get those `console.log` statements for the filtered elements, which I'm not getting. According to the documentation the filter(elements) should work.

Comment: elements yes, jquery object yes,  array no. But why wouldn't you just store the first collection as a variable in the first place?

Comment: `var $txtInputs = $('input[type=text]'); $('input').filter($txtInputs).each(...` but filter makes no sense for that as it is the same as doing `$txtInputs.each(..`

Comment: First of all, this was just an example -- in real life I have business logic that restricts elements. The general problem is post-selector filtering from an arbitrary Element Array. Secondly, `$('input').filter($(subset)).each(function(i, item)` with the `$` in front of subset doesn't work either.

Comment: So why can't you just loop over the array? `$.each(subset, function...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i, item) {
   subset.push(item);
});
```

You must change `subset.push($(this))` with `subset.push(item);`

```js
var subset = [];
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i, item) {
   subset.push(item);
});

// Filter by Elements array
 $('input').filter(subset).each(function(i, item) {
    console.log('Filtered from array: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
 });
 console.log('end');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1"/><br/>
<input type="textarea" id="textarea1"/><br/>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogroup"/>Radio1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogroup"/>Radio2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radiogroup"/>Radio3<br/>

<input type="text" id="text2"/><br/>
```